# Why i am getting bad request when i was sending request to chatgpt api

Tags: asp.net, openai-api

Getting a bad request after catch error message. When i trying to get chat GPT response using the API, it cannot be done, at first is state is the endpoint problem then i fixed it but now it become HTTP Error: Bad Request

```
protected async Task GetChatGPTResponse(string paragraph)
{
    string apiKey = "removed";
    string chatCompletionsEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

    try
    {
        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set the authorization header
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

            // Set the base address to the chat completions endpoint
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(chatCompletionsEndpoint);

            // Prepare the request data
            var requestData = new
            {
                prompt = paragraph,
                model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k", // Adjust the model as per your requirement
                max_tokens = 50
            };

            // Serialize the request data to JSON
            string requestDataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);

            // Prepare the HTTP content
            var content = new StringContent(requestDataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Send POST request to the chat completions endpoint
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);

            // Check if request was successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Read the response content
                string chatGptResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                lblChatGptResponse.Text = chatGptResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error response
                lblChatGptResponse.Text = $"HTTP Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = $"HTTP Error: {ex.Message}.";
        errorMessage += $"<br />Request URI: {chatCompletionsEndpoint}";
        errorMessage += $"<br />Request Method: POST";
        //errorMessage += $"<br />Request Content: {requestDataJson}";
        // Add more details as needed
        lblChatGptResponse.Text = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect a "400 - Bad Request" response to contain details of specific errors. Did you try checking the response content for any clues?

Comment: Is your URI chatCompletionsEndpoint  correct?

Comment: What is the error message returned, usually you get an error object returned with parameters like `message` and `type`, etc that will give us more information.